# Can a vertically-scrolling row contain both a normal element, and a horizontally-scrolling element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a row element, containing a normal div, and a horizontally-scrollable div. I want the row to itself be vertically-scrollable.

i.e. if I scroll down, it all scrolls down together.

I've included a jsfiddle showing my attempt:

https://jsfiddle.net/dfj1cb0o/1/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
  <div class="large-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div class="large-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

div {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.first {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, pink);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.second {
  background: linear-gradient(blue, purple);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.large-content {
  min-width: 1000px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 1000px;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your usage of `flexbox`. By default the `align-items` value is `stretch`. This makes the items, in a `row` direction, stretch from top to bottom. This messes with the height of the `.first` and `.seconds` divs.

To fix this set the the `align-items` value to `flex-start`. This aligns everything from the top of the row.

Further try to specify the width of the `.first` and `.seconds` divs to make sure they are in the proper dimensions. Avoid using the following:

```
max-width: 300px;
min-width: 300px;
```

This will be equeal to the more simple:

```
width: 300px; /* Use this! */
```

Try out the example below to see the result.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.first {
  width: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, pink);
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.second {
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(blue, purple);
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.large-content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
  <div class="large-content"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div class="large-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Emiel thanks for getting back to me. You code snippet doesn't seem to allow me to scroll the second div horizontally. I can only vertically scroll both divs. I'm on a Mac though, might that be why?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom first, then you'll see the horizontal scrollbar there. ;)